# Is this a bug using sizeof...() operator?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, sizeof, variadic-templates

I came across what looks like strange behavior from the clang++ compiler for the sizeof...() operator:

```
template <typename... Args>
void test(tuple<Args...> t) {
    cout << "size: " << sizeof...(Args) << endl;
}

...
test(make_tuple(1, 2)); // prints 'size: 10'
```

I realize that the more standard method would be:

```
template <typename... Args>
void test(tuple<Args...> t) {
   cout << "size: " << tuple_size<tuple<Args...> >::value << endl;
}

test(make_tuple(1, 2)); // prints 'size: 2'
```

But I'm still curious as to why I get the weird values for the first version. Is the value of sizeof...() undefined for this case, or is the compiler misbehaving?

Comment: Are you using `boost::tuple` instead of `std::tuple`? That would explain these symptoms and I could post an answer. If not, what's your compiler/standard library, and what version?

Comment: I'm using std::tuple and clang++ version: Apple clang version 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-421.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.0.0
Thread model: posix

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This sounds a lot like a mismatch between old variadic template emulation and true variadic templates.

Before variadic templates came along, people could emulate them with a finite number of defaulted template parameters:

```
struct void_ {}; // marker type not used anywhere else

template <typename T0 = void_,
          typename T1 = void_,
          typename T2 = void_,
          typename T3 = void_,
          typename T4 = void_,
          typename T5 = void_,
          typename T6 = void_,
          typename T7 = void_,
          typename T8 = void_,
          typename T9 = void_>
struct tuple { /* blah blah magic here */ };
```

This allows one to write `tuple<int>`, and `tuple<int, double>`, and so on, up to ten parameters.

`tuple_size` can then be implemented by counting the number of template parameters before the first `void_`. The rest of feature set is implemented in a similar vein.

Sadly, this trick interacts quite poorly with true variadic templates. When given `tuple<int, double>`, the type deduction on `tuple<Args...>` will deduce the `Args` pack to be { int, double, void_, void_, void_, void_, void_, void_, void_, void_ }. This is why `sizeof...(Args)` returns 10: there are indeed ten types in that pack, even if eight of them are just markers that we decided to assign the meaning of "no type to see here, move along".

The compiler doesn't know about our convention, so it counts everything. `tuple_size` knows about this convention and counts only the actual types we care about.

Comment: Glad I clicked on this question, I've been wondering how I might go about simulating variadic macros considering that the VS 2012 team spent all their time ugly-ifying the interface rather than adding support for C++11 features. How, exactly, would I count up the number of template parameters before the first `void_`? Do you have a good reference for this little trick?

Comment: @CodyGray the most straightforward solution would be with ten partial specializations :). I don't think there are any smarts that can help you there (I haven't looked at the boost implementation, but checking that is a good idea). Alternatively, you could use Boost.MPL; I'm sure there's something like that in there.

Comment: Damn, ten partial specializations isn't much better than the copy-paste that I have now. :-( I was hoping to reduce the amount of code I have to duplicate in each specialization.

Comment: This makes sense. Looking at '/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/tr1/repeat.h' I see exactly that (except it's called _NullClass). I'm guessing that while the clang++ supports variadic templates, they haven't switched over all their libraries yet.